# && operator overloading and assignments in C# - Clarification?

Tags: c#

Following [this **very** interesting issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4509#issuecomment-130391723)  which was originated from [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31961411/roslyn-failed-to-compile-code) question  -

I want to take *1 steps back please*  (removed the dynamic environment) :

Looking at this code : ( <sub>[a variant of this one](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4509#issuecomment-130391723)</sub>)

```
void Main()
{
    int a;
     int b = 100;
    Console.WriteLine(X.M(1, out a));

}

public class X
{
    public  int H=0;

    public static X M(int x, out int y)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("x = "+x);
        y = x;
        return new X(x);
    }

    public X(){}

    public X(int h)
    {
        H=h;
    }

    public static bool operator false(X x)     {Console.WriteLine("in false operator for "+ x.H); return true; }
    public static bool operator true(X x)      {Console.WriteLine("in true operator for "+ x.H); return true; }
    public static X operator &(X a, X b)       {Console.WriteLine("in & operator for "+ a.H+","+b.H);   return new X(); }
    public static implicit operator bool (X x) {Console.WriteLine("in bool operator for "+ x.H);return true; }
}
```

The result is :

```
x = 1
in bool operator for 1
True
```

This is understood :

- The `x = 1` is from the method itself ( using `Console.Writeline`)
- `in bool operator for 1` is from the implicit operator from `X` to `Bool` 
  (so - `Console.WriteLine` treats the whole expression as `Console.Writeline(bool)`)
- The last "True" is from the "return true" in the  `operator bool (X x)`

OK - So let's change

```
Console.WriteLine(X.M(1, out a));
```

to

```
Console.WriteLine(X.M(1, out a) &&  X.M(2, out b));
```

Now - the result is  :

```
x = 1
in false operator for 1
in bool operator for 1
True
```

**2 questions** :

1. Why does this `in false operator for 1` executes ? I don't see any reason for `false` to be present here.
2. I could understand why the right part in `X.M(1, out a) &&  X.M(2, out b)` won't executes ONLY if the left part is `false` - but again I don't see how the left part can be false. It does return `true` (according to my first code)

NB

I've read many times the answers from the post :

Jon said :

> The second && is a normal && between two bool expressions - because
>   Nop returns bool, and there's no &(X, bool) operator... but there is a
>   conversion from X to bool.
>
> So it's more like:
>
> bool first = X.M(1, out a) && X.M(2, out b);
>   if (first && Nop(a, b))
>
> Now first is true even though only the first operand of && has been
>   evaluated... so b really hasn't been assigned.

Still I don't understand : *"first is `true`(????) even though only the first operand of && has been evaluated"*

Comment: If the `false()` operator returns `true` then it means that the operation returns `false` ("is x false? yes it is (return true;)")! It isn't an `operator bool()`.

Comment: The `false()` operator is called to short-circuit the `&&`... They could have called the `true()` operator, but for example the definition of `&&` in [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx): *except that **if x is false**, y is not evaluated*

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5203515/613130 : *&& is defined as a short-circuiting operator; **if the first operand evaluates false**, it is demanded to short circuit there and not evaluate the right hand side.*

Comment: @xanatos Yes. but that'st the problem I dont see where the first operand gets to have a false value.

Comment: You `return true;` in `operator false(X x)` (`{Console.WriteLine("in false operator for "+ x.H); **return true;** }`). Try changin it to `return false;`

Comment: @xanatos Sorry  , I might be nagging but why does the control gets into `operator false(X x)  ` at first place ???

Comment: Because the `&&` operator is translated to if (not operator false(left expression)) then calculate right expression

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, don't forget that this is deliberately bizarre code, used to find a corner case. If you ever find a type that behaves like this in a genuine program, find the author and have a quiet word with them.

> Still I don't understand : "first is true(????) even though only the first operand of && has been evaluated"

Yes, because of the way the `&&` operand is handled in the case where the operands aren't `bool`. It's specified in section 7.12.2 of the C# spec:

> The operation `x && y` is evaluated as `T.false(x) ? x : T.&(x, y)` where `T.false(x)` is an invocation of the `operator false` declared in `T`, and `T.&(x, y)` is an invocation of the selected operator in `&`. In other words, `x` is first evaluated and `operator false` is invoked on the result to determine if `x` is definitely false. Then, if `x` is definitely false, the result of the operation is the value previously computed for `x`. Otherwise, `y` is evaluated, and the selected `operator &` is invoked on the value previously computed for `x` and the value computed for `y` to produce the result of the operation.

So, in order:

- `X.M(1, out a)` is invoked, to get a result - call it `op1` for the moment
- Next `X.false(op1)` is invoked, and returns `true`
- Then by the above, the result of the expression `X.M(1, out a) &&  X.M(2, out b)` is `op1`
- Next, the value of the conversion from `op1` to `bool` is invoked, and that returns `true`. This is due to overload resolution for `Console.WriteLine`.

To answer your specific confusion:

> but again I don't see how the left part can be false.It does return true (according to my first code)

It returns a value which is somewhat contradictory - it's `false` in that the `false` operator returns `true`, but it's `true` in that the conversion to `bool` returns `true`. Once you understand that it's the value returned by the `false` operator which determines whether or not to evaluate the second operand of `&&`, it should all be clear.

Comment: But why does it invoke ```operator bool```? As I interpret the spec, the result of the ```&&``` operation should just be the result of the ```operator &``` call.

Comment: @erikkallen: This depends on the context :) In the context of the `Console.WriteLine` call, it's because there's an overload accepting `bool`, and that's more specific than the overload accepting `object`. In the original context of Neal Gafter's program, it was because the result was going to be used as the first operand in *another* `&&` expression, where the right hand expression was of type `bool`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I must say that I am rather surprised that it will use implicit operators to locate more specific overloads.